# UE5: GetScreenSpacePosition() always return (0,0)

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4, unreal-umg

I'm trying to extract the **mouse position** from `FPointerEvent`, but no matter what, it always return the coordinate of (0,0).

Note that I'm aware of `APlayerController::GetMousePosition()` function, but I'll be implement the same to dragging UMG so getting mouse properties from player controller won't work

[image: code]

Btw, I'm using **UE5**

Comment: Screenspace position is a vector of 2 `float`s but you are trying to print 2 `int` with `"%d,%d"`. Change `TEXT("%d,%d")`  to `TEXT("%f,%f")`

Comment: Alternatively you could also use the `ToString` function with `TEXT("%s"), *InMouseEvent.GetScreenSpacePosition().ToString()`

Comment: damn, I'm now informed. It costs me a day swearing at the engine. How silly, thanks for help man